# What to do when someone vandalizes his post and account?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/120445/plagiarism) has been vandalized by its author. He also vanished his Workplace account.

His account contained his real name, his company and location. His other SE sites' accounts still contains such PI.

One can assume he does not want his boss to see this, or his coworkers. I assume he can't delete the question because of the answers.

What should we do with this kind of behaviour ? Flag for moderator's attention ? Or just let go ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flag as "in need of moderator intervention" and describe what's going on in the subsequent reason box that pops up.

If you have sufficient reputation, it's ok to roll back the edit on a clear vandalisation.  But do leave a flag as this lets us know if we need to deal with any fallout.

Comment: It appears that the person just didn't want his real name associated with that question, and thus edited it to jibberish in panic. Isn't it better to _first_ flag the question so that someone can anonymize the abandoned user and then roll-back an edited version of the original question?